# Pie Charts with advanced design

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

I am trying to create a pie chart ( rounded percentage bar ) with an advanced design.

Check the following links to see the design ( ignore the percentage, also the gradient is optional ).

[image: First chart design]

[image: Second chart design]

The problem is I can't figure how to have a rounded element at the end of the bar.

I would also like the chart to be animated ( please check Easy Pie Chart for the animation )

I tried with a lot of jQuery plugin but without success.

The idea is to have the chart generated by jQuery getting the information needed ( percentage / bar color / track color ) from the div.

e.g

```
<div class="chart" data-percent="73" bar-color="#225333" track-color="#ffffff">73%</div>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var x = 200;
var y = 200;
var r = 50;
var ROTATION = 0;

function setcanvas() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ctx.rotate((Math.PI/180)*(-ROTATION));
  ctx.translate(-x,-y);

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle="black";
  ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function getPoint(c1,c2,radius,angle) {
  return [c1+Math.cos(angle)*radius,c2+Math.sin(angle)*radius];
}

function setPercent(uplimit) {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ROTATION=270;
  ctx.rotate((Math.PI/180)*ROTATION);
  ctx.translate(-x,-y);
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.strokeStyle="red";
  ctx.arc(x,y,r,(Math.PI/180)*(uplimit),0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  var a = getPoint(x,y,r,(Math.PI/180)*(uplimit))[0];
  var b = getPoint(x,y,r,(Math.PI/180)*(uplimit))[1];
  nr = 5;
  ctx.arc(a,b,nr,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.stroke();
}

function callcanvas(degree) {
  setcanvas();
  setPercent(360-degree);
}

var degree = 180;
var start = 0;
var it = window.setInterval(function() {
  callcanvas(start);
  start++;
  if(start == degree) {
    start = 0;
    window.setInterval(it);
  }
},20);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

its not totally correct.I does not know jquery.But I think this can be done by html5 canvas. first of all you will have to make a circle of radius R in canvas and then use blue colored arc function in canvas to make arc of D degree.Obviously there should be a javascript function that take the value D and make the appropriate arc and then you can place the blue dot at x = xCenter + radius * cos(angle) y = yCenter + radius * sin(angle). I will provide you the exact code after some time.

Comment: Even better if it doesn't need jQuery and only a simple javascript.  Awaiting for more information, thanks a lot

Comment: The code is posted below, you just need to set the degree in javascript code , you can check the output in my website http://vitideas.in/web/ :-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help.
I still have some questions.  1. Is there a way to replace the color with a gradient? I tried with ctx.createLinearGradient but doesn't seems to work ( result in a solid color )  2. Is there a way to have the bar going from the left side to right side  3. How to make the script run only once? 4. Is there a way to speed the animation?

Comment: yup you can speed up the animation by changing the value of setInterval from 20 to any value , the smaller the value the faster will be the speed.For rest 2 I will get you the new code soon.

Comment: I have posted new code.This one is perfect.You can change the values shape and color. :-) the code is available at my website http://vitideas.in/web/newcode/ ,try to upvote my code please.

Comment: Thanks a lot awesome!  Just a last question, how to stop the repeat? I would like to run the script only 1 time

Comment: You can stop it.For repetition I mentioned window.setInterval(it); at the if statement (start==degree), replace this line "window.setInterval(it);" to "window.clearInterval(it);" and your animation will stop as soon as start becomes degree. You can also place your own functions here if you want that will trigger or run at the stop of this animation.

Comment: Awesome, this is perfect! I really want to upvote your answer but it seems I need 5 more reputation to be able to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

```js
//======== CONFIGURATION WINDOW
//======== i made this configuration code here you can change value and experiment
var x = 200;//set the x - center here
var y = 200;//set the y - center here
var r = 50;//set the radius here
var linewidth=50;//set the line width here
var SET_COLOR="#00FFFF";//set the color here
var SET_PERCENTAGE = 85 //set the percentage here
//======== 

var loaded = false;
window.onload = function() {
  var status=document.getElementById('status');
  status.style.top=y+'px';
  status.style.left=x+'px';
  loaded = true;
}


var ROTATION = 0;
function setcanvas() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ctx.rotate((Math.PI/180)*(-ROTATION));
  ctx.translate(-x,-y);

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle="black";
  ctx.arc(x,y,r+(linewidth/2),0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.globalAlpha=0.1;
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle="black";
  ctx.arc(x,y,r-(linewidth/2),0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function getPoint(c1,c2,radius,angle) {
  return [c1+Math.cos(angle)*radius,c2+Math.sin(angle)*radius];
}

function setPercent(uplimit) {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ROTATION=270;
  ctx.rotate((Math.PI/180)*ROTATION);
  ctx.translate(-x,-y);
  ctx.lineWidth = linewidth;//40
  ctx.strokeStyle=SET_COLOR;
  ctx.arc(x,y,r,(Math.PI/180)*(uplimit),0);
  ctx.globalAlpha=1;
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  var a = getPoint(x,y,r,(Math.PI/180)*(uplimit))[0];
  var b = getPoint(x,y,r,(Math.PI/180)*(uplimit))[1];
  nr = linewidth/2;
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle="white";
  ctx.arc(a,b,nr,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle="white";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  var a = getPoint(x,y,r,(Math.PI/180)*(uplimit))[0];
  var b = getPoint(x,y,r,(Math.PI/180)*(uplimit))[1];
  nr = linewidth/2-3;
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle="white";
  ctx.arc(a,b,nr,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle=SET_COLOR;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

function callcanvas(degree) {
  setcanvas();
  setPercent(360-degree);
}

var degree = parseInt((SET_PERCENTAGE*360)/100);
var start = 0;
var it = window.setInterval(function(){
  callcanvas(start);
  start++;
  if(start == degree) {
    start = 0;
    window.setInterval(it);
  }
  if(loaded) 
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = parseInt((start*100)/360)+'%';
},1);
```

```html
<div style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;' id='status'>
  0%
</div>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```